# Canvas Height options "Auto-resize" vs "Fluid" in App Settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

A question about **Canvas Height** setting in the Facebook Settings.
There are 2 options `Auto-Resize` and `Fluid` and they seem to function in the same way.
In the [Canvas Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/), it seems that the 2nd option should be `scroll bars` for Canvas Height, so I'm assuming that `Fluid` option is a new feature.

But what is the difference between Canvas Height set to `Auto-Resize` or `Fluid`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/

Answer (score 0):

If you would have placed your cursor over the question sign near the Canvas Height option, you might have seen this:

"Settable allows you to set the height via FB.Canvas.setSize() method in JavaScript SDK with default set to 800px. Fluid sets the height dynamically to fit the page and shows scrollbars if content exceeds the page size."

Also, the options are not Auto-Resize and Fluid, but Settable and Fluid

Comment: The change from 'Auto-Resize' to 'Settable' is a very recent change in the last few days.  It still may be rolling out to new users and still appear as 'Auto-Resize'.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, a day after I posted this question, the option "Auto-resize" was changed to "Settable", which is much more clear.